# Ubuntu 22.04, Firefox does not fit when expanded

Tags: firefox

[image]

I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 and this started.  So I have to sneak under the top bar with cursor, shrink window then expand and then it fits.

[image]

Is there a fix?

Comment: try ```CTRL``` + ```TAB``` and ``CTRL``` + ```SHIFT``` + ```TAB``` to switch between tabs. or try a another shell theme or use it how it is ate the second image.

Comment: I believe what I did was to uninstall the snap version of firefox and install the other version that is not snap but now I'm on WSL2 so don't have this problem.